# Monit from epel not able to start via upstart method

Tags: centos, monit

I have centos 6.3 machine and did a yum install monit (version 
monit 5.1.1-4.el6 from epel) and then I setup the up the http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/Upstart and tried to start monit  initctl start monit
initctl: Job failed to start. I did on another machine I download the .rpm file of monit-5.3.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm and did the the same and able to start via initctl method. What could be missing in the epel version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're entirely different versions. The [official Monit release](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is at version 5.5 right now.
 
EPEL is at version **5.1.1-4.el6**.
RepoForge is at version **5.4-1.el6.rf**.

Use the newer Monit available from RPMForge/RepoForge. The old one available via EPEL doesn't support the feature you wish to use.

Comment: @ewhite I am planning to take the version 5.5 from the official site. But I guess I need to rpmbuild it right? Will it have any depedency problem with centos 6.3?

Comment: Honestly, I just use the RPMforge version on my CentOS 6.x systems. 5.4 gives you what you need and will be more compatible with your OS distribution (in terms of the daemon and config file formats).

Comment: How to install from the rpmforge? Can I just download the .rpm file and do rpm -ivh to it? Will that be ok?

Comment: You use it the same way you use EPEL. The [RPMForge instructions are here](http://repoforge.org/use/). Otherwise, just [download the package](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/monit/monit-5.4-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm) and install it.

Comment: the EPEL method is yum install but first I have set the repo as RPMForge correct me ? The downloaded one I got to install using rpm -ivh?  Is there any deficiency or difference in both method?

Comment: EPEL and RPMForge can coexist. If you just need this package, use the download link I provided.

Comment: yes mine is minimal installation so just need this package only. After that I ran rpm -ivh is this correct method to run it?

Comment: I did this rpm -ivh monit-5.4-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm. Then I set the /etc/init/monit.conf and then I tried to run initctl reload-configuration and finally I get this  initctl start monit
initctl: Job failed to start. Just to confirm the installation I did this rpm -qa | grep monit monit-5.4-1.el6.rf.x86_64